# Build libraries for deployment

Tags: c, dll, lua, luarocks

So I am working on making a plugin for an application that uses Lua, I've spoken with the main developers and they said that if I want to use an external library such as `luafilesystem` or `luasocket` that I would need to build it into a `dll`.

I have little experience with `C` let alone building `dll`s for that matter. I also don't have LuaRocks or anything like that but if I just downloaded LuaRocks and installed the library using that to my personal environment, and I just use what it generates (hopefully a `dll`? I don't use Lua for anything else and I don't want to mess anything up in my own environment without knowing first that it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

LuaRocks would download the `dll` directly, you can use the `dll` without building.
Lua external library is easy for using. Just `require` the correct path.